# information_schema and performance_shema in MySql

Tags: mysql

what is information_schema and performance_shema in MySql? These two schema databases presents in mysql default. What does they works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Information_schema` contains metadata about databases in mysql. For e.g. names of tables,columns in a database etc. performance_schema is  for monitoring MySQL Server execution at a low level. The `performance_schema` is intended to provide access to useful information about server execution.
For more info check  [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html) and  [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)